# Script to filter/display two seperate category types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting two filter categories to work together.  The desired result is for only divs to display when the month from the drop down list is selected and when the region check boxes are checked.

a giant plus would be for a counter to display showing the number of displayed divs vs total divs.

here is the code i have now.

```
        <select name="month-select" id="month-select">
        <option id="select">Select a Month</option>
        <option value="jan" id="jan" name="jan">January</option>
        <option value="feb" id="feb" name="feb">February</option>
        <option value="mar" id="mar" name="mar">March</option>
        <option value="apr" id="apr" name="apr">April</option>
        <option value="may" id="may" name="may">May</option>
        <option value="jun" id="jun" name="jun">June</option>
        <option value="jul" id="jul" name="jul">July</option>
        <option value="aug" id="aug" name="aug">August</option>
        <option value="sep" id="sep" name="sep">September</option>
        <option value="oct" id="oct" name="oct">October</option>
        <option value="nov" id="nov" name="nov">November</option>
        <option value="dec" id="dec" name="dec">December</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="red" id="red" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor"><label for="ck-loc-us">red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="green" id="green" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor"><label for="ck-loc-us">green</label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="blue"onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor"><label for="ck-loc-us">blue</label>

    <input type="checkbox" value="selectall" id="selectall"onclick="Color.filterByColorSelectAll();" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor"><label for="ck-loc-us">select all colors</label>
    <div id="fulllist">
    <div class="rResult red jan mar apr may">
        <h3>Spring and January</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rResult blue apr may dec">
        <h3>April May December</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="rResult green jul">
        <h3>July Only</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                  <li>Stuff</li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
    </div>
<div id="filtersContainerUpdatingMessage">
    <p>Updating...</p>
</div>

<div class="divsShowing">
    Showing
        <span class="textForALL">ALL ( </span>
        <span class="divsShowing"> </span> of <span class="divsTotal"> </span>
        <span class="textForALL">) </span>
    Divs
</div>

<div class="divsShowingAreZero">
    <p>Please select a color and/or different month.</p>
</div>
    </div>
     <script>
        $('#month-select').change(function(){
            $('.rResult').each(function(){
                if ($(this).hasClass($('#month-select').val())) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: sorry, this is the right jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/dexf6ekL/ 
 
here is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dexf6ekL/  each div will only have one color class assigned to it but possibly multiple months assigned. But only want the divs to display when the drop down month is selected with the combination of color(s) checked.

Comment: this gives you a good start , http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/2kGzZ/164 i hope it is very easy to write the remaining logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below approach. This is unified way of handling filters.

Please note the below points.

- A new class for check boxes are added for except for `selectall`
- All change functions will call the same common function , selectall will check and uncheck color check boxes and then calls the common function.

```js
$('#month-select').change(function() {
  window.filter();
});
window.Color = {
  filterByColor: function() {
    window.filter();
  },
  filterByColorSelectAll: function() {
    if ($("#selectall").is(":checked"))
      $(".checkColor").prop("checked", "checked");
    else
      $(".checkColor").removeProp("checked");
    window.filter();
  },
}
window.filter = function() {
  var month = $('#month-select').val();
  if (month == null || month == "")
    $('.rResult').show(); //show all
  else {
    $('.rResult').hide(); // hide all 
    $('.rResult.' + month).show(); //filter by month
  }
  var strColorFilter = [];
  var checkedItems = $(".checkColor:not(:checked)").map(function(i, o) {
    return "." + o.id;
  }).get();
  //filter by color
  if (checkedItems.length == 0) return;
  strColorFilter.push(".rResult:visible"); //take on visible after month filter
  strColorFilter.push(checkedItems);
  $(strColorFilter.join("")).hide();
}
```

```css
.rResult {}
```

```html
<select name="month-select" id="month-select">
  <option value="" id="select">Select a Month</option>
  <option value="jan" id="jan" name="jan">January</option>
  <option value="feb" id="feb" name="feb">February</option>
  <option value="mar" id="mar" name="mar">March</option>
  <option value="apr" id="apr" name="apr">April</option>
  <option value="may" id="may" name="may">May</option>
  <option value="jun" id="jun" name="jun">June</option>
  <option value="jul" id="jul" name="jul">July</option>
  <option value="aug" id="aug" name="aug">August</option>
  <option value="sep" id="sep" name="sep">September</option>
  <option value="oct" id="oct" name="oct">October</option>
  <option value="nov" id="nov" name="nov">November</option>
  <option value="dec" id="dec" name="dec">December</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" value="red" id="red" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="ck-loc-us">red</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="green" id="green" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="ck-loc-us">green</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="blue" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="ck-loc-us">blue</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="selectall" id="selectall" onclick="Color.filterByColorSelectAll();" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="ck-loc-us">select all colors</label>
<div id="fulllist">
  <div class="rResult red jan mar apr may">
    <h3>Spring and January</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rResult blue apr may dec">
    <h3>April May December</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>

  <div class="rResult green jul">
    <h3>July Only</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
      <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>
  <div id="filtersContainerUpdatingMessage">
    <p>Updating...</p>
  </div>

  <div class="divsShowing">
    Showing
    <span class="textForALL">ALL ( </span>
    <span class="divsShowing"> </span> of <span class="divsTotal"> </span>
    <span class="textForALL">) </span> Divs
  </div>

  <div class="divsShowingAreZero">
    <p>Please select a color and/or different month.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/2kGzZ/165